# Install Shield LE: Change location of certmgr.exe

Tags: installshield-le

I am getting the following error during a Build in Install Shield LE:

> ISEXP : error : -1024: File C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\certmgr.exe not found. Cannot stream the file into the Binary table

Searching for the certmgr.exe, I found it in ...\Windows Kits\8.1\bin... while Install Shield LE is looking in ...\8.0...

I wish to know if its okay to just paste a copy of certmgr.exe in ...\8.0... so that my Install Shield can find it? Or is there a way to update the path information of certmgr.exe inside Install Shield?

Comment: Do you have an exe custom action that references this file, causing it to be included? Note that you are unlikely to have redistribution rights for this file.

Comment: @MichaelUrman
I do have a custom action that runs an executable. This executable adds an X509Certificate2 under (StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine).
 
But the code that builds that executable, does not contain any references to certmgr.exe anywhere.


Does certmgr.exe work if copied from one folder to another?

Note: This build error occurs the first time I try to build. If I build again immediately after this error, a successful build is reported. But no new MSI is generated during this second build. The MSI that I find has the timestamp of the first build.

Comment: Huh. If you don't reference certmgr, InstallShield shouldn't be trying to add it, and especially not from an incorrect location. If you do, it shouldn't succeed on every other build. Perhaps examining the output from a failing `iscmdbld.exe /v ...` would yield more hints. (Is that available in LE?)